# Receive data from input return json string

Tags: angular

I have a question about angular js 2.
Who can talk to me how to receive data from input and return json string?

This's my code: http-test.component.ts

```
    <form action="POST">
        UserName 
        <div>
            <input type="text" required id= "username"/>
        </div>
        Password 
        <div>
            <input type="password" required id= "password" />
        </div>
        Name 
        <div>
            <input type="text" required id= "name"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type ="submit"> Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
`,
styles:[`
    table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    }
`],
providers: [HttpTestService]
```

})

```
customers: Object;
constructor( private _httpService:HttpTestService){}
//Return Object json
onTestTable(){
    this._httpService.getCurrentTime()
        .subscribe(
        customers => this.customers = customers.records
        );

//On init when load page
ngOnInit(){
    this.onTestTable();
}
```

}

This's code Service: http-test.service.ts

```
constructor(private _http: Http) { }
getCurrentTime() {
    return this._http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php')
            .map(res => res.json())
}
postJson(){
}
```

I want to receive data from input and return json string then post that json string to service when I press Submit. How can I do?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Post some code snippet or more details about your question or what you have tried so far so that we can understand what is your problem exactly.

Answer (score 1):

To receive data from an input, you could leverage the valueChanges property of control and build a JSON string in its associated callback with `JSON.stringify()`:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <input [ngFormControl]="ctrl"/>
    {{jsonString}}
  `
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.ctrl = new Control();
    this.ctrl.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      // receive the value

      // build the string string from the value
      // leveraging JSON.stringify()
      this.jsonString = (...)
    });
  }
}
```